# How to edit natbib \bibliographystyle{dcu} to preferred format?

Tags: latex, bibliography

I am editing the reference style to meet the requirement of a journal.

I used natbib package in Latex and tried many different bibliographystyles. Only dcu are closed what I want, but still not the same. The dcu style is shown below:

[image]

However, I would like to remove the brackets of years, and also make the names of journals to be non-italics. How do I edit them? If there are some styles more closed to my preferred style, that is also great. Thank you so much!